# Rubyでアルファベットのみの26進数をつくりたい

Tags: ruby

Rubyでアルファベットだけの26進数をつくりたいのですがどうしたらよいのでしょうか。

integer.to_s(26)
にすると数字とアルファベットの組み合わせになってしまいます。

Comment: 仮に`a`が`0`だとすると、１０進での２６は`ba`(`z`の次が`ba`)になってしまいますがそれが望む動作ですか？ 例えば表計算ソフトのカラムのようなものをイメージするなら`z`の次が`aa`ですが・・

Comment: `Hexavigesimal`と呼ばれるものですかね？ Excelのセルのようなゼロ無しのやつは `Bijective base-26` と呼ばれているようです。ゼロを割り当てないパターンでは桁数固定で出したいとき(十進なら頭ゼロ埋めしたい状況)に困るような気はしますが。 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexavigesimal

Answer (score 10):

`String#tr` で `tr("0-9a-p", "a-z")` としてはいかがでしょうか。

```
0.to_s(26).tr("0-9a-p", "a-z")
#=> "a"
25.to_s(26).tr("0-9a-p", "a-z")
#=> "z"
26.to_s(26).tr("0-9a-p", "a-z")
#=> "ba"
```

個人的には 0 が a になるのはスゴく違和感があります^^;

Answer (score 4):

Excel列名変換問題 試験会場がこちらと聞いて。

```
class Fixnum
  def bijective_s(base=nil, offset=nil)
    offset ||= 'A'.ord #65
    base ||= 26
    value = self
    result = []
    while value > 0
      value -= 1
      result << (value%base+offset).chr
      value /= base
    end
    result.reverse.join
  end
end
```

0.bijective_s   #=> ""
1.bijective_s   #=> "A"
26.bijective_s  #=> "Z"
27.bijective_s  #=> "AA"
53.bijective_s  #=> "BA"
702.bijective_s  #=>"ZZ"
703.bijective_s  #=>"AAA"

いや。再帰をケチっただけなんですがね。

Answer (score 3):

関数で実装すると以下のようになります。

```
def dec26(num)
  table = ('a'..'z').to_a
  num > 25 ? dec26(num/26)+table[num%26] : table[num%26]
end
```

しかし、上記の方法だと再帰するたびにtableがスタックに積み上げられるため、以下のほうが負荷が少ないです。

```
def dec26(num)
  (num > 25 ? dec26(num / 26) : '') + ('a'.ord + num % 26).chr
end
```

Comment: `tr()` が存在しなかったなら、自分にはその再帰が一番分かりやすいと感じられました。ただ、再帰毎に `table` を作る部分がコスト高です。こうして一行にするのはどうでしょう。 `def dec26(num) (num>25?dec26(num/26):'')+('a'.ord+num%26).chr end`

Comment: 反映しました。ありがとうございますm(_ _)m

Answer (score 2):

INPUTとOUTPUTの例を示してもらえると助かります。
特に桁が繰り上がるときの仕様がハッキリしていないと、お望みの回答が出てこない恐れがあります。

とりあえず、かなり昔に「Excel列名変換問題」と称してExcelと同じようなカラムの数え方（？）をするようなプログラムを書いたことがあります。  
実行例はこんな感じです。

```
1 => A
26 => Z
27 => AA
16384 => XFD
```

昔に書いたコードなのでリファクタリングの余地は大きいと思いますが、参考までに載せておきます。

```
class ExcelColConv
  AZ_LENGTH = 'Z'.ord - 'A'.ord + 1 #26
  OFFSET_NUM = 'A'.ord - 1 #64

  # 数字からアルファベット
  def to_col_string(col_num)
    convert_num '', col_num 
  end

  def convert_num(ret, n)
    if n == 0
      ret
    else
      quo, rem = excel_divmod n
      convert_num (rem + OFFSET_NUM).chr + ret, quo # 再帰           
    end
  end    

  def excel_divmod(n)
    quo, rem = n.divmod AZ_LENGTH
    rem == 0 ? [quo - 1, AZ_LENGTH] : [quo, rem]
  end
end

conv = ExcelColConv.new
[1, 26, 27, 16384].each do |n|
  str = conv.to_col_string(n)
  puts "#{n} => #{str}"
end
```

この問題に関するブログも書いているので、よかったら読んでみてください。

[Excel列名変換問題をRubyとPerlとC#とF#で書いてみた](http://blog.jnito.com/entry/20111231/1325311566)

Answer (score 1):

単純に２６進変換するのを書いてみました。

```
class Integer
    def to_26_a
        n = self
        if n == 0
            "a"
        else
            table = [*'a'..'z']
            result = ""
            while n > 0
                result += table[n % 26]
                n /= 26
            end
            result.reverse!
        end
    end
end

puts(0.to_26_a) #a
puts(1.to_26_a) #b
puts(25.to_26_a)#z
puts(26.to_26_a)#ba
```