# ExcelのC1R1形式からセルのラベル（A1、C7）形式への変換

Tags: kotlin, excel

KotlinでPOIを使ったプログラミングをしているのですが、その中でセルの座標（x=5、y=4）からセルのラベル（座標は0から開始のためこの場合F3）に変換する効率的なアルゴリズムがないかを知りたいです。

26進法で考えていますが、A〜Zまで来た次がAAのため簡単にできないと思っています。

以下、テストで作成し正しく動くものはできてはいます。ただ、直感的にわかりやすいプログラムではないため、もう少しわかりやすいものができないかと試行錯誤しています。

```
@JvmStatic
fun cellIndexToCellName(x: Int, y: Int): String {
    var cellName = ""
    var threshold = 26
    var tempX = x
    var loop = 0 // ループの2回目以降は値から1を引く
    while (true) {
        val mod26 = tempX % threshold
        cellName =  (mod26 + 65 - loop).toChar() + cellName
        if (tempX < threshold) {
            break
        }
        tempX = tempX / threshold
        if (loop == 0) {
            loop += 1
        }
   }
   return cellName + (y + 1)
}
```

Kotlinで書いていますが、Java、C、C#等の言語でも構いません。

Comment: 参考情報: [Rubyでアルファベットのみの26進数をつくりたい](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/6083)

Comment: 以前にもあったんですね、検索してなかったです。この内容で確認してみます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

参考URLを元にKotlinの場合のコードを書きました。結果的に次のようなコードでうまくいきました。

```
@JvmStatic
fun cellIndexToCellName(x: Int, y: Int): String {
    var cellName = dec26(x, 0)
    return cellName + (y + 1)
}

@JvmStatic
fun dec26(num: Int, first: Int): String {
   return if (num > 25) { dec26(num / 26, 1) } else { "" } + ('A' + (num - first) % 26)
}
```

firstは一種のフラグです。2桁目以上は何もしていないとZの次がBAになってしまうのを防ぐために使っています。

dec26関数の最初の呼び出しの際は0、再帰で呼び出す際は1を渡し、値の調整をしています。